# How to solve differential equation $y'=2y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

How to solve differential equation $y'=2y$ when $y(7)=6$ ?

The answer is $6e^{2(x-7)}$, but i don't get how come it is $(x-7)$?

I know that it is from formula of $y(x)=Ce^{kx}$, where $C=6$ and $k=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [*Separable Equation*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx)

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{y}~ dy = \int 2 ~dx \implies y(x) = ce^{2 x}$$

Using the I.C.

$$y(7) = c ~e^{2 \times 7} = c~ e^{14} = 6 \implies  c = 6 ~e^{-14}$$

Substitute back

$$y(x) = c~ e^{2x} = 6~ e^{-14} e^{2x} = 6~ e^{-14 + 2 x} =  6 ~e^{2(x-7)}$$